# Actionscript 3.0 TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: flash, actionscript, typeerror

I'm a beginner in flash and currently I'm having a problem .
I'm making a game, it's like space invader.
It's was good at the start.
However, when the characters hit the enemy, 
it prompt me error.

TypeError:

> Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object
>   reference.    at _fla::MainTimeline/frame1126()   at
>   flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()    at Enemy/eFrame()

I do not know what is wrong with it .
Can anyone help me?

Here the source for my timeline

```
stop();
//these booleans will check which keys are down
var leftDown:Boolean = false;
var upDown:Boolean = false;
var rightDown:Boolean = false;
var downDown:Boolean = false;
//how fast the character will be able to go
var mainSpeed:int = 5;
//how much time before allowed to shoot again
var cTime:int = 0;
//the time it has to reach in order to be allowed to shoot (in frames)
var cLimit:int = 12;
//whether or not the user is allowed to shoot
var shootAllow:Boolean = true;
//how much time before another enemy is made
var enemyTime:int = 0;
//how much time needed to make an enemy
//it should be more than the shooting rate
//or else killing all of the enemies would
//be impossible :O
var enemyLimit:int = 16;
//the player's score
var score:int = 0;
//this movieclip will hold all of the bullets
var bulletContainer:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
addChild(bulletContainer);
//whether or not the game is over
var gameOver:Boolean = false;

//adding a listener to mcMain that will move the character
mcMain.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveChar);
function moveChar(event:Event):void{
    //checking if the key booleans are true then moving
    //the character based on the keys
    if(leftDown){
        mcMain.x -= mainSpeed;
    }
    if(upDown){
        mcMain.y -= mainSpeed;
    }
    if(rightDown){
        mcMain.x += mainSpeed;
    }
    if(downDown){
        mcMain.y += mainSpeed;
    }
    //keeping the main character within bounds
    if(mcMain.x <= 0){
        mcMain.x += mainSpeed;
    }
    if(mcMain.y <= 0){
        mcMain.y += mainSpeed;
    }
    if(mcMain.x >= stage.stageWidth - mcMain.width){
        mcMain.x -= mainSpeed;
    }
    if(mcMain.y >= stage.stageHeight - mcMain.height){
        mcMain.y -= mainSpeed;
    }
    //Incrementing the cTime

    //checking if cTime has reached the limit yet
    if(cTime < cLimit){
        cTime ++;
    } else {
        //if it has, then allow the user to shoot
        shootAllow = true;
        //and reset cTime
        cTime = 0;
    }

    //adding enemies to stage
    if(enemyTime < enemyLimit){
        //if time hasn't reached the limit, then just increment
        enemyTime ++;
    } else {
        //defining a variable which will hold the new enemy
        var newEnemy = new Enemy();
        //making the enemy offstage when it is created
        newEnemy.y = -1 * newEnemy.height;
        //making the enemy's x coordinates random
        //the "int" function will act the same as Math.floor but a bit faster
        newEnemy.x = int(Math.random()*(stage.stageWidth - newEnemy.width));
        //then add the enemy to stage
        addChild(newEnemy);
        //and reset the enemyTime
        enemyTime = 0;
    }
    //updating the score text
    txtScore.text = 'Score: '+score;
}
//this listener will listen for down keystrokes
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, checkKeysDown);
function checkKeysDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
    //making the booleans true based on the keycode
    //WASD Keys or arrow keys
    if(event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 65){
        leftDown = true;
    }
    if(event.keyCode == 38 || event.keyCode == 87){
        upDown = true;
    }
    if(event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 68){
        rightDown = true;
    }
    if(event.keyCode == 40 || event.keyCode == 83){
        downDown = true;
    }

    //checking if the space bar is pressed and shooting is allowed
    if(event.keyCode == 32 && shootAllow){
        //making it so the user can't shoot for a bit
        shootAllow = false;
        //declaring a variable to be a new Bullet
        var newBullet:Bullet = new Bullet();
        //changing the bullet's coordinates
        newBullet.x = mcMain.x + mcMain.width/2 - newBullet.width/2;
        newBullet.y = mcMain.y;
        //then we add the bullet to stage
        bulletContainer.addChild(newBullet);
    }
}
//this listener will listen for keys being released
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, checkKeysUp);
function checkKeysUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
    //making the booleans false based on the keycode
    if(event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 65){
        leftDown = false;
    }
    if(event.keyCode == 38 || event.keyCode == 87){
        upDown = false;
    }
    if(event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 68){
        rightDown = false;
    }
    if(event.keyCode == 40 || event.keyCode == 83){
        downDown = false;
    }
}
```

Here are the source code from ENEMY.

```
//This is the basic skeleton that all classes must have
package{
    //we have to import certain display objects and events
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;
    //this just means that Enemy will act like a MovieClip
    public class Enemy extends MovieClip{
        //VARIABLES
        //this will act as the root of the document
        //so we can easily reference it within the class
        private var _root:Object;
        //how quickly the enemy will move
        private var speed:int = 5;
        //this function will run every time the Bullet is added
        //to the stage
        public function Enemy(){
            //adding events to this class
            //functions that will run only when the MC is added
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED, beginClass);
            //functions that will run on enter frame
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);
        }
        private function beginClass(event:Event):void{
            _root = MovieClip(root);
        }









        private function eFrame(event:Event):void{
            //moving the bullet up screen
            y += speed;
            //making the bullet be removed if it goes off stage
            if(this.y > stage.stageHeight){
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);
                _root.removeChild(this);
            }

            //checking if it is touching any bullets
            //we will have to run a for loop because there will be multiple bullets
            for(var i:int = 0;i<_root.bulletContainer.numChildren;i++){
                //numChildren is just the amount of movieclips within 
                //the bulletContainer.

                //we define a variable that will be the bullet that we are currently
                //hit testing.
                var bulletTarget:MovieClip = _root.bulletContainer.getChildAt(i);


                //now we hit test
                if(hitTestObject(bulletTarget)){
                    //remove this from the stage if it touches a bullet
                    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);
                    _root.removeChild(this);
                    //also remove the bullet and its listeners
                    _root.bulletContainer.removeChild(bulletTarget);
                    bulletTarget.removeListeners();
                    //up the score
                    _root.score += 5;
                }
            }

            //hit testing with the user
            if(hitTestObject(_root.mcMain)){
                //losing the game
                _root.gameOver = true;
                _root.gotoAndStop('lose');
            }

            if(_root.gameOver){
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);
                this.parent.removeChild(this);
            }
        }
        public function removeListeners():void{
            this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good suggestions below... But in regards to the actual error: if you use the debug Flash player it will tell you the line number where the error is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

There are several design errors in you script:

- don't create a field for root because it is not only redundant, but leads to bad design. Also, you don't clean up when the clip is removed (which is something different the deleted).
- _root can be null, because if i'm not mistaken, Event.ADDED is also dispatched when a DisplayObject is added to a DisplayObjectContainer.
- for every Enemy an Event.ENTER_FRAME handler is registered. This might lead to performance issues and spagetti code - let a container handle its children (search for game loop in your specific context).

I'd recommend implementing a safe remove method, when a child wants to remove itself.

```
function remove():void {
  if (parent) parent.removeChild(this); // otherwise an run time error might be thrown
}
```

And regarding the error thrown in eFrame. It is really hart to say, what is null:

- stage: which is only available after Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE
- _root.bulletContainer: you just typed _root to Object, no further information given
- _root.mcMain: you just typed _root to Object, no further information given

I can only recommend a cleaner approach to coding which would include strong typing